How to deploy microfront on aks?
currently in a test environment a website has been developed with Angular which it has been placed in a docker image with nginx and it is deployed on an AKS within a pod and service that listens on port 8080.
The path where the web page is located is /usr/share/nginx/html
This is the nginx configuration
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page  404 /index.html;
    location = /index.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page  400 401 403 404  /40x.html;
    location = /40x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

Istio is being used to expose the page where a virtual service has been configured that will receive requests /
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: login
  namespace: microfront
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - login
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: login
        port:
          number: 8080

When microfront development began, an mf folder was created inside the pod of the website in /usr/share/nginx/html and the microfronts began to be placed inside.
And they call each microfront that is inside the mf folder with the following website configuration
  apiStdHome: {
    mock: false,
    ip: 'http://XXXXX/',
    consolidated_position: 'mf/consolidated',
    detail_accounts: 'mf/details',
    accounts: 'mf/accounts',
    transfers: 'mf/transfers',
  }

If for example I wanted to place all the contents of the consolidated folder in another pod, what changes should I make to the nginx configuration of the website? And what configuration should I use in the pod where the microfront will be?
